# How to get Create Statement of Table in some other database in Spark using JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, impala

Problem statement:

1. I have a Impala database where multiple tables are present
2. I am creating Spark JDBC connection to Impala and loading these tables into spark dataframe for my validations like this which works fine:

   ```
    val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
                 .option("url","url")
                 .option("dbtable","tablename")
                 .load()
   ```
3. Now the next step and my actual problem is I need to find the **create statement** which was used to create the tables in Impala itself
4. Since I cannot run command like below as it gives error, is there anyway I can fetch the show create statement for tables present in Impala.

   ```
   val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
                 .option("url","url")
                 .option("dbtable","show create table tablename")
                 .load()
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use Spark SQL "natively" to execute something like

```
val createstmt = spark.sql("show create table <tablename>")
```

The resulting dataframe will have a single column (type string) which contains a complete `CREATE TABLE` statement.

But, if you still choose to go JDBC route there is always an option to use the good old JDBC interface. Scala understands everything written in Java, after all...

```
import java.sql.*
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url")
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show create table <tablename>")
...etc...
```

Comment: Issue is that the table of which I need the ddl or show create statement is present in some DB like MySQL. I need to make a jdbc connection to read that table and jdbc provides only load method which expects the select statement only. Passing this statement in .option("dbtable","show create table tablename") returns error.

Comment: So I did NOT understand your question, and Impala actually has nothing to do with it... :)

Comment: rephrased the problem statement. Hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Does your Spark run on a separate cluster? I.e. why do you need JDBC?

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Even though I looked at your answer just now but I also did the same and was able to get the results in the morning. This needed to be solved with plain old Java/Scala JDBC connection code rather than spark APIs. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for your help